# Passing parameters from input bar

Tags: angularjs

I want to create an input bar where I can submit zip code that I later use to find pizzerias that deliver to that zip code. Queries aside, I have a problem with sending the zipCode. Any suggestions?

home.html

```
    <div class="bar">
        <form ng-submit=submit() ng-controller="zipCodeController">
            <p><b>Wpisz kod pocztowy np. 30-069</b></p>
            <input type="text" ng-model="text" name="text"/>
        </form>
    </div>
```

main.js

```
app.controller('zipCodeController', ['$scope', $location, function($scope, $location) {
$scope.zipCode = '';
$scope.text = 'Wpisz adres pocztowy np. 30-069';
$scope.submit = function () {
    if ($scope.text) {
        $scope.zipCode.push(this.text);
        $scope.text = '';
    }
    $location.path('/pizzeriaList/'+$scope.text);
}

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
// Home
    .when("/", {templateUrl: "partials/home.html", controller: "PageCtrl"})
    // Pages
    .when("/about", {templateUrl: "partials/about.html", controller: "PageCtrl"})
    .when("/contact", {templateUrl: "partials/contact.html", controller: "PageCtrl"})
    .when("/pizzeriaList", {templateUrl: "partials/pizzeriaList.html", controller: "PageCtr"})
    .when("/p/:id", {templateUrl: "partials/pizzeria.html", controller: "PageCtrl"})
    .when("/p/:id/:pid", {templateUrl: "partials/addPizza.html", controller: "PageCtrl"})
    .when("/cart", {templateUrl: "/partials/cart.html", controller: "PageCtrl"})
    .when("/pizzeriaList/:zipCode", {templateUrl: "/partials/pizzeriaList.html", controller: "PizzeriaListCtrl"})
    .otherwise("/404", {templateUrl: "partials/404.html", controller: "PageCtrl"});


app.controller('PizzeriaListCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.zipCode = $routeProvider.zipCode;
})
```

Comment: Check the Developer Console for error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what services are for, they can be injected into each component that needs to share data.

```
app.service('zipCodeService', function() { return { zipCodes:[] }; });
```

add it to your dependency list in your component

```
app.controller('zipCodeController', ['$scope', '$location', 'zipCodeService', function($scope, $location, zipCodeService)
```

and now add zipCode to the service not your scope

```
zipCodeService.zipCodes.push(this.text);
```

Any other component you want to access that array from you inject the service and it is the same instance of the array.